# Select input cannot have a default value (Vue.js)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3, vee-validate

Trying to set a default value to a simple select input with "selected" doesn't work.

I am making a blog in Vue.js and the blog posts can be assigned to different categories. However, when editing a post, I want the select input to have a default value if the post is already inside a category. The pseudo-code would look like so: "if category.id equals post.category.id".

This is my input:

```html
<label>
  <VeeValidateField name="post_category" as="select">
    <option value="" disabled>Set to folder</option>
    <option value="0">none</option>
    <option v-for="category in categories"
      :key="category.id"
      :value="category.id"
      :selected="category.id === post.category.value"
    >
      {{ category.category_name }}
    </option>
  </VeeValidateField>
</label>
```

Although there can be a default value with a multiple select input, that is not my use case.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?!

Thank you!

Comment: Is `post.category.value` actually the ID that you're trying to match on in `:selected`?

Comment: @MattU yes that's the property I want to match.

Comment: Is either value a different data type? I suspect that maybe one of them is a `Number` type and the other is a string. If that's the case, `===` won't work. Does it work with `==` instead? If so, you can `console.log(typeof category.id)` and for the other, and it'll show you the underlying data type of each.

Comment: @MattU so actually I solved it by using v-model and initializing its value to the following expression: "this.$props.login ? this.$props.login.login_category.value : ''," so the select input either has a default value or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by using v-model and setting the value in data to the following expression:

```
data() {
    return {
      categoryValue: this.$props.login ? this.$props.login.login_category.value : ""
    }
  }
```

and this is the markup:

```
<label>
    <VeeValidateField v-model="categoryValue" name="login_category" as="select">
        <option value="" disabled>Set to folder</option>
        <option value="0">none</option>
        <option v-for="category in categories"
                :key="category.id"
                :value="category.id">
          {{ category.category_name }}
        </option>
    </VeeValidateField>
</label>
```

So when the property `categoryValue` evaluates, the select input either gets a default value or none at all.